# rust-analyzer error and warning when cargo run is working fine

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

I have a package that contains both a binary crate and a library crate. The structure of the package looks like this

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── bin.rs
│   ├── lib.rs
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── concrete.rs
│   │   └── traits.rs
│   └── foo.rs
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "mycrate"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

src/lib.rs:

```
pub mod foo;
```

src/foo.rs:

```
pub mod concrete;
pub mod traits;
```

src/foo/traits.rs:

```
pub trait A {
    ...
}
```

src/foo/concrete.rs

```
use crate::foo::traits::A;
pub struct B {
    ...
}
impl B {
    ...
}
impl A for B {
    ...
}
```

And finally src/bin/bin.rs:

```
use mycrate::foo::concrete::B;
use mycrate::foo::traits::A;

fn main() {
    let b: B = ...
    // use methods defined in trait A
}
```

The problem is in the last file both my use statements are having problems according to rust-analyzer

```
use mycrate::foo::traits::A;
```

For the above I am getting an unused import warning (but if I don't include it the code won't compile because I use methods defined in A so it needs to be in scope)

```
use mycrate::foo::concrete::B;
```

And for above I am getting an `unresolved import mycrate::foo::concrete, could not find concrete in foo` error.

Strangely if I run `cargo run` or `cargo build` it works without any warnings or errors.

`rustup --version` (https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install):

```
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.71.1 (eb26296b5 2023-08-03)`
```

`rust-analyzer --version` (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rust-analyzer):

```
rust-analyzer 0.0.0 (99718d0c8 2023-07-22)
```

`hx --version` (my text editor installed from https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/helix)

```
helix 23.05 (7f5940be)
```

`hx --health | grep rust`

```
rust                      ✓ rust-analyzer           ✘ lldb-vscode             ✓                         ✓                         ✓
```

I am on a MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Max chip running macOS 13.0.1 (probably not relevant, but including just in case)

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Does the error come from rustc or rust-analyzer? (It should appear next to the error).

Comment: I am using helix. It does not say where the error is coming from, there is a code next to it though in parens. The unresolved import is (E0432) and for ununsed import it says (unused imports). I assume it is rust-analyzer because the code compiles without any warning or error. Also if I uninstall rust-analyzer it goes away. I am still able to use go to definition on the unresolved import while rust-analyzer is installed which is also weird, because if it was unresolved why is it able to jump to the code for me

Comment: Editted post to include editor information